# credit card number and expiry date checking in java

Tags: java, struts, credit-card, payment-processing

In struts 1.3 , i have a payment.jsp,

- Credit Card Number.
- Credit Card Type.
- Card Holder Name.
- Expiration Date.
- CVV Number.
- Comments.

The action form PaymentForm has the validations for the creditCardNumber as

```
!GenericValidator.isCreditCard(creditCardNumber)

, & expairy date to select the MM & YYYY.
```

my question is , On submit button Then there should be an API (standard) which should validate the credit card details and process the payments. 
So which api i should use ?

Comment: Did you search before posting this question?

Comment: hmm so in your application you have direct access to all the credit card details..that doesn't sound safe to me

Answer (score 1):

You will need a (payed) subscription to a [Payment Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_service_provider) and use the API they possibly provide. Usually, you will need generate a URL and make a post with this URL.